# django как добавить поле в select

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня довольно сложный запрос.
Я делаю `join` нескольких таблиц, потом группирую и некоторые поля рассчитываю через `sum()`:

```
my = MyModel.objects \
            .select_related('car') \  # join 2ю таблицу
            .exclude(status='bad') \
            .values('car_id', 'car__state_number') \  # вот тут я группирую 
            # а вот тут надо мне получить некоторые поля, это у меня ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ
            .annotate(shift_count_sum=Sum('shift_count'),mileage_sum=Sum('mileage'),
                      odometer=Max('end_odometer'),
                      end_odometer=Sum('end_odometer'),
                      # не получается сделать ЭТО! тоесть вернуть просто значение поля, без функций
                      # end_odometer=Value('end_odometer'),
                      )
```

Если я добавлю нужное мне поле в `values()` - оно попадает в `GROUP BY` и тем самым группировка ломается. Надо как-то не добавлять его в `values()`. Как можно просто добавить поле? Уже перепробовал все варианты `=Value` - всегда ошибка.

Как мне получить просто поле, без функций типа `sum`, `count`, `avg`, а просто поле `новое_поле=Value('поле')`?

Comment: А почему бы просто SQL не написать? Ну ведь получите даже лучше, и времени сэкономите - вагон. ORM - он для простых случаев, а для сложных, ну пока нет ничего лучше, чем SQL.

Comment: Этого даже и с SQL не получится! Если поля нет в group by, тогда ему обязательно положена агрегатная функция (да хоть [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629431/django-annotating-with-a-first-element-of-a-related-queryset), который берет первый попавшийся элемент - это имеет смысл, если они скорее всего одинаковые). А если добавить поле в `values` у вас неправильный вывод? Если я вас правильно понял - у вас ничего не получится в принципе. Либо публикуйте короткие примеры входных и выходных данных, а также не забудьте, пожалуйста, **что именно за ошибка** выдается - это важно.